# Burninate [npm-start]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

#### About the tag

The `npm start` command is a shorthand for `npm run start` or executes `node server.js` in the case of an absence of a start script in `package.json`.

The tag [npm-start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm-start) has a minimal wiki and no wiki excerpt.

It has 183 questions, but due to the minimal amount of things to be explained about `npm start` (well, it's just a CLI alias - end of story), I've only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619269/what-is-the-difference-between-yarn-run-and-npm-start) question that directly focuses on the tag. The rest of the questions basically added the tag because they used `npm start` before facing an issue.

Also... I fail to imagine how can someone become an expert in `npm-start`!

#### [Burnination criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate)

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?** No. `npm start` can run an arbitrary script, which itself has to be described in the answer. Adding or removing this tag to a question *can not* bring further infos to a question.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?** Absolutely not. Common usages include starting a server, or a dev server - and these can be already pretty different! Also once again, the *arbitrary script* argument: different context is (likely) to equate different `npm start` behavior.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?** It does not describe the content of the question. As said before, the behavior of `npm start` has to be explained in the question. As such, it is ambiguous because `npm start` can refer to the launch of any script. It is actually the *question* that has to explain the *tag*, but it should be the other way around!

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?** Yes. But that is not a sufficient condition to be a relevant tag.

Comment: it could probably be replaced by [tag:npm-scripts]

Comment: The *become an expert in a tag* argument is flawed. The relevant question is: do the experts *use* the tag to find question they want to answer. Removing the tag disables 22 watchers. Bad/minimal or missing wiki's and excerpts are not an argument to burn a tag.

Comment: @rene by *becoming an expert*, I was talking about gaining badges in a particular tag! Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @rene the wiki remarks were no as much an *argument* for deletion but rather a precision so that readers could quickly get to what extent is the community involved in this tag without doing research by themselves

Comment: There is also [tag:npm-install] (another npm-scripts related command) with 2,561 questions.

Comment: **[tag:npm-install] is completely different**! It installs modules, check caches, run potential post/pre install scripts... It *does not* runs an arbitrary script, there are *often* questions about the exact behavior of `> npm install` (cache mechanism, meaning of `-S`, etc), and it *is not* a shorthand running the `package.json#scripts.install`

Comment: It seems to be mostly questions like "I used `npm start` and look at these errors I got" which in the overwhelming majority of cases the reason is user code. As such I do think the tag actively causes harm because it is misused and shifts focus away from the actual problem.

Answer (score -9):

I disagree with burninating this tag because:

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?** Yes. It describes that the question is about running a script through `npm start` or `npm run start`.

Sure, the script that's being executed varies and could be basically anything, but that's irrelevant for the tag usage. With that reasoning, tags like [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) could also be burninated, as questions using that tag could be about web applications, desktop applications, ... . Just like the type of application is irrelevant to the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag, the type of script is irrelevant to the [npm-start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm-start) tag.

Lastly, since this burnination criteria is mostly used to identify meta tags, I fail to see how this would be a meta-tag.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?** Yes, as you already mentioned.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?** Yes, though very minimal. As mentioned, the tag implies that someone is trying to run a script using `npm start` or `npm run start`. What I mean with "minimal" is that it does add little information over using the [npm-scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm-scripts) tag.

For example, let's say we have four questions using the following tags:

1. [npm-start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm-start)[webpack-dev-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webpack-dev-server)
2. [webpack-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webpack-cli)[webpack-dev-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webpack-dev-server)
3. [npm-scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm-scripts)[webpack-dev-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webpack-dev-server)
4. [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js)[webpack-dev-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webpack-dev-server)

Just looking at the tags, I can guess that:

- Question 1 and 3 are about running a webpack server using npm scripts
- Question 2 is about running the webpack server through their own CLI
- Question 4 is likely about running the webpack server programmatically

As each scenario could have their own experts, I do think that this is a meaningful tag.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?** Looking at the questions using that tag, I'm not seeing any other usage except for being used when the question is about running an application/test/script using `npm start`. In many cases it's irrelevant to the question itself, but the context is the same.

---

So summarized, this is a tag that's on-topic and unambiguous, though there's little benefit when using it. The question is, is it worth the effort to burninate a tag like this? Does it cause any harm? Does it make questions less likely to be answered or found? I personally don't believe they do.

If anything should happen, I would rather synonymize [npm-start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm-start) to [npm-scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm-scripts).

Comment: Tag creation says that should be a topic that hasn't been asked before. This particular one has been asked well before.

Comment: The four questions you mentionned can very potentially be the exact same